# Search with in List Web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

We have a Site page in SharePoint online site. On the modern site page We have a list webpart. We need to add a search box in that list web part to search keywords with in the list. The default search box on the site page search the site. We need to search within the list itself. Any suggestions to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for SharePoint in Microsoft 365, the Search Box Web Part is available only in classic experience.

So we couldn't add the list search box in modern site page.

Reference:

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-configuring-the-search-box-web-part-b167ca75-b493-4f8b-8af6-ec94de1feb12#:~:text=To%20add%20a%20Search%20Box%20Web%20Part&text=Click%20Add%20a%20Web%20Part,Click%20Add](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-configuring-the-search-box-web-part-b167ca75-b493-4f8b-8af6-ec94de1feb12#:%7E:text=To%20add%20a%20Search%20Box%20Web%20Part&text=Click%20Add%20a%20Web%20Part,Click%20Add).

Answer (score 0):

Modern Sharepoint listview werbpart you can't do a search unless you click the 'See All' link located at the top right corner of the webpart and redirected to the list itself and from there you will do the search.

Options you can do is modify the SharePoint search results source , its located in the site settings
[image]

(but that I won't recommend since you all your search including not related to the list will be affected)

You can also look on [spfx custom webpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) and create a listview with a searchbox that will search specifically only in the list you wanted.